# iOS9 CRASH: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, exception, nsarray

In iOS9 my app SWPi crash in main.m:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int retVal = 0;

    @try
    {   NSLog(@"MAIN:");
        retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {   NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
        NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
    }
    @finally
    {   [pool release];
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

trace:

```
2015-09-19 12:31:57.197 SWPi[441:79241] MAIN:
2015-09-19 12:31:57.533 SWPi[441:79241] CRASH: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
2015-09-19 12:31:57.550 SWPi[441:79241] Stack Trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x22de96a3 <redacted> + 150
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34762e17 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   Foundation                          0x23b69903 <redacted> + 110
3   Foundation                          0x23b69abf <redacted> + 442
4   Foundation                          0x23b3c9c9 <redacted> + 3764
5   Foundation                          0x23b3ba6d <redacted> + 276
6   UIKit                               0x27332f57 <redacted> + 1110
7   UIKit                               0x27334f1d <redacted> + 196
8   UIKit                               0x27143d19 <redacted> + 48
9   UIKit                               0x26f1f34d <redacted> + 260
10  UIKit                               0x27142d61 <redacted> + 1232
11  UIKit                               0x27155db9 <redacted> + 36
12  UIKit                               0x271403cf <redacted> + 134
13  FrontBoardServices                  0x2ad82ccf <redacted> + 230
14  FrontBoardServices                  0x2ad82fc1 <redacted> + 48
15  CoreFoundation                      0x22dacc3f <redacted> + 14
16  CoreFoundation                      0x22dac82d <redacted> + 452
17  CoreFoundation                      0x22daab9b <redacted> + 794
18  CoreFoundation                      0x22cfe249 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
19  CoreFoundation                      0x22cfe035 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
20  UIKit                               0x26f18b2d <redacted> + 524
21  UIKit                               0x26f138a9 UIApplicationMain + 144
22  SWPi                                0x00015f6f main + 182
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x34eae873 <redacted> + 2
```

)

Under iOS8 all is right.
Where may be a problem?

Debug after inserting breakpoint for all exceptions:

```
2015-09-19 13:35:16.322 SWPi[454:85641] MAIN:
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x14e89, 0x34762df0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x34762df0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x22d03d7e CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 622
frame #2: 0x26fe40d4 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _navigationItems] + 240
frame #3: 0x272181e6 UIKit`-[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 886
frame #4: 0x23b3c630 Foundation`_decodeObjectBinary + 2844
frame #5: 0x23b3ba6c Foundation`_decodeObject + 276
frame #6: 0x271ba5cc UIKit`-[UINavigationBar initWithCoder:] + 404
frame #7: 0x23b3c630 Foundation`_decodeObjectBinary + 2844
frame #8: 0x23b3ba6c Foundation`_decodeObject + 276
frame #9: 0x271b6bfe UIKit`-[UINavigationItem initWithCoder:] + 734
frame #10: 0x23b3c630 Foundation`_decodeObjectBinary + 2844
frame #11: 0x23b3ba6c Foundation`_decodeObject + 276
frame #12: 0x271fa904 UIKit`-[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 460
frame #13: 0x27333ce2 UIKit`-[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 218
frame #14: 0x23b3c630 Foundation`_decodeObjectBinary + 2844
frame #15: 0x23b3ba6c Foundation`_decodeObject + 276
frame #16: 0x273339f0 UIKit`-[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 160
frame #17: 0x2733404c UIKit`-[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 52
frame #18: 0x23b3c630 Foundation`_decodeObjectBinary + 2844
frame #19: 0x23b427d2 Foundation`-[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1378
frame #20: 0x23adf2da Foundation`-[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 318
frame #21: 0x23b3c630 Foundation`_decodeObjectBinary + 2844
frame #22: 0x23b3ba6c Foundation`_decodeObject + 276
frame #23: 0x27332f56 UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1110
frame #24: 0x27334f1c UIKit`-[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 196
frame #25: 0x27143d18 UIKit`-[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 48
frame #26: 0x26f1f34c UIKit`-[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
frame #27: 0x27142d60 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1232
frame #28: 0x27155db8 UIKit`__84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3181 + 36
frame #29: 0x271403ce UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 134
frame #30: 0x2ad82cce FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 230
frame #31: 0x2ad82fc0 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 48
frame #32: 0x22dacc3e CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
frame #33: 0x22dac82c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 452
frame #34: 0x22daab9a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 794
frame #35: 0x22cfe248 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
frame #36: 0x22cfe034 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
frame #37: 0x26f18b2c UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 524
frame #38: 0x26f138a8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 144
  * frame #39: 0x00074f8e SWPi`main(argc=1, argv=0x00920b54) + 182 at main.m:7
```

*** EDIT**

The trouble is in main xib.
iOS4-8 ignore it, iOS9 not.

In text mode:

```
<navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Item" id="R9S-B3-9Aq"/>
```

This item is visible in Xcode in Outlets of the parent controller, but no outlet reference in xib in text mode. 
In Xcode this outlet has been with another gray from like others, and I cant delete it. 
After deleting this line of the xib in text mode, and outlet & references in parent *.m & *.h app run normally.

Comment: Could you post the code that cause the crash?

Comment: I cant, this happens before any my code started

Comment: Suspect a zombie pointer.

Comment: @theWalker - The information in your "EDIT" section fixed it for me. There was a rouge "navigationItem" that was leading to crashes in iOS 9.1 and removing and readding it fixed issue. Just weird. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you are inserting a nil object into an array somewhere in your code. The debugger isn't great about reporting the source line where an error occurs. It might show it as being in main.m, but that is clearly wrong.

Try setting a global breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions. That will often cause Xcode to show you the actual line that is causing your crash. (No need to use a try/catch in main.m, and it may even confuse things.)

### EDIT:

OK, I think I see what you changed in your answer. You added a second stack trace.

Does your crash log still claim that the error is occurring in main.m? From the second crash log, it looks like there may be a problem in opening the view controller scene for your initial view controller. There's a reference to _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion in the stack trace, and then later, `-[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:]` (Internally Storyboards actually contain nibfiles.

My guess is that there is some subtle corruption in your root view controller in your storyboard. There's also a call to `-[UINavigationController _navigationItems]`. That suggests that maybe theres a problem with the navigation items in your root view controller.

I gather that your app uses a navigation controller as your root view controller?

Comment: You said "see in editet queston." What does that mean? I don't see any meaningful edits to your question in response to my answer.

Comment: Tmp I was delete NavigationController and app runs. As you wrote, problem is  about this.

Comment: With this, @Duncan C: "...That suggests that maybe theres a problem with the navigation items in your root view controller...". Explanation in *EDIT.